# Чем плоха авторизация через htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть простенькая страница с админкой, авторизация в админку сделана через htaccess и htpasswd.
Поясните, пожалуйста, чем плохая такая авторизация?
Опыта php разработки не много.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это небезопасно: username / password передаются открытым текстом *с каждым* запросом. С https это не большая проблема, но у вас, скорее всего, сайт открывается только по незащищённому протоколу http?

Comment: Да, по протоколу http

Comment: По http любой снифер трафика где угодно между клиентом и сервером сможет «подслушать» логин и пароль. Может, воспользоваться любым php фреймворком, который предоставляет возможность создания пользователей и их авторизации? Или, например, [этим классом](https://github.com/PHPAuth/PHPAuth)?

Comment: С фреймворком понимаю, с помощью yii2 делал, но сейчас пробую сделать для одностраничника админку без фреймворка.
Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Sergiks протокол прозрачен для фреймворков. им абсолютно наплевать http там или https, они могут, при некоторых настройках, плеваться ошибками или не работать, но они не занимаются шифрованием трафика, а если занимаются, то не должны. Для правильной работы с http/https надо настраивать веб-сервер

Comment: Боюсь, что с принятием новых законов https у нас фактически окажется под запретом.

Comment: @avp спокойствие, только спокойствие! Пока не приняли, надеюсь, и не примут. Вето-шмето, лобби, выборы, новая дума. Политика, манёвры. Без https интернета нет, равно как и с государственным MiM.

Comment: @strangeqargo фреймворки обычно в курсе, по какому протоколу к ним зашли. Что с этим дальше делать – решает разработчик. Суть не в этом, а в том, что HTTP Basic Auth шлёт введённые логин/пароль с каждым HTTP запросом: на каждую картинку, скрипт, новую страничку. Хотя, наверное, это ничем не хуже других вариантов авторизации, когда сессионные куки передаются с каждым запросом, или логин-пароль один раз, при авторизации – так же можно перехватить.

Comment: вот именно, поэтому трафик должен шифроваться веб-сервером

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы добавить админа, удалить админа или  сменить пароль, придётся редактировать `.htpasswd` каждый раз.

Comment: Это не проблема, админ только один

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас одностраничник, то это хорошый вариант. Так как никто не будет замарачиваться с однастраничником который не принесет ни какой выгоды. Только про бэкапы не забывайте.